# Espresso UI Testing, Cannot check loading state, How to test UI with live data and view model?

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso, ui-testing, dagger-hilt

Currently i am implementation UI test/ Instrumentation Test with Espresso, to test FragmentMovie at loading state, and success state. Due to multiple test library and other stuff,my test Instrumentation must contains hilt ijection.

UI testing scenario :

1. When loading state, Check my loading progressbar and text loading is displayed
2. When succes state, hide loading, and show recycle view
3. Done

## Problem

`Loading state` is skiped when running test. `@Test` will run after ViewModel `postValue` Success state. So, I can't test while loading state.

when i not write `onView(withId(R.id.progressBar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))` the test is passed, but  i want to test while loading state.

Possible fix, add `delay(10000)` to my view model, that will extend duration of loading state, but, my test still waiting success state.

Currently i am not use IdlingResource, because that not fix my problem,

Actual scenario:

1. Fragment Run,
2. ViewModel fetchdata,
3. ViewModel loading,
4. ViewModel success,
5. FragmentTest run,
6. viewAssert failed,

Expected :

1. Fragment Run,
2. ViewModel fetchdata,
3. ViewModel loading,
4. FragmentTest check progressbar,
5. ViewModel success,
6. FragmentTest check recycleView,
7. done

Why? and How?

## Code

Observer from fragmentMovie

```kotlin
 private val viewModel: MovieViewModel by viewModels()

   [...]

 viewModel.movie.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            Log.d(TAG, "viewModelgetMovie: ${it.status}")
            when (it.status) {
                Status.LOADING -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "loading..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.txLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                    if (it.data != null) {
                        list.addAll(it.data)
                        movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
                Status.ERROR -> {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.txLoading.text = it.message
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

viewmodel

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class MovieViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MovieRepository,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : ViewModel() {

    // new code
    private val moviePost = MutableLiveData<ResourceHelper<ArrayList<MovieData>>>()

    val movie: LiveData<ResourceHelper<ArrayList<MovieData>>>
        get() = moviePost

    init {
        fetchMovie()
    }

    private fun fetchMovie() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            moviePost.postValue(ResourceHelper.loading(null))
            repository.getMovie(1).let { movie ->
                moviePost.postValue(movie)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

MovieFragmentTest

```kotlin
package com.unlink.moviecatalogue6.ui.movie

import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId
import androidx.test.ext.junit.rules.ActivityScenarioRule
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import com.unlink.moviecatalogue6.MainActivity
import com.unlink.moviecatalogue6.R
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidRule
import dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltAndroidTest
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class MovieFragmentTest {
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    var activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {

    }

    @Test
    fun happyPath() {
        onView(withId(R.id.progressBar)).check(matches(isDisplayed())) // error
        // how can i test on loading?
        onView(withId(R.id.recycleMovie)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

## Error

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user
Got: "ProgressBar{id=2131231016, res-name=progressBar, visibility=GONE, width=1080, height=44, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@a455ee2, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}"
```

The error shown because my progress bar has gone. Because my test check the progress bar after success state.

## Screenshoot

> Loading state, but my test not run @Test

[loading state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjV0L.png)

> Success state, then @Test start

[success state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBBMD.png)

> that cause error view is gone

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsKeo.png)

> Any response will very appreciated

Comment: did you got the solution, if yes, please share,

Comment: not yet, espresso always skip loading state, or maybe espresso mark them (viewModelScope or coroutineScope) as IdlingResource. so i can't test loading state.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue when running a test, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do this is to pause dispatcher with testDispatcher inside your test before loading then resume it manually.

```
private val testDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

@Test
fun happyPath() {
    testDispatcher.pauseDispather()
    onView(withId(R.id.progressBar)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    testDispatcher.resumeDispather()
    onView(withId(R.id.recycleMovie)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

One note you should move your loading outside of viewmodel scope.

```
   moviePost.setValue(ResourceHelper.loading(null))
   viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        
        repository.getMovie(1).let { movie ->
            moviePost.postValue(movie)
        }
    }
```

You can read more about this here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-survey#4